# TFS: merging a branch back to a trunk folder that's since been renamed

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2005, tfs, merge

I'm using TFS and trying to merge a branch back to the trunk from which it was made. Trouble is, the Source Control Merge Wizard has no entries in its Target Branch dropdown list.

I suspect this is because the trunk was *renamed* after the branch was made. Is there a simple way that I can still perform the merge and have TFS recognise that the two branches are actually related?

I know very little about baseless merges, but is this the sort of thing they're used for?

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't work.  Renames shouldn't stop the Merge Wizard from discovering the branch hierarchy.  Was the original relationship created with the Branch command or with a baseless merge?

Comment: It was using the Branch command. Right-click on the trunk folder in Source Control Explorer and select Branch. And yeah, I was surprised/disappointed to find it tripped up by a rename too. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the [TF command-line utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx). There are some features of TFS (even in 2008) that are only available from the command line. See the merge command.

**I have not tried this**, and TFS under 2005 was not particularly stable IMHO. (It got much better after 2008 and SP1.) I would recommend replicating the scenario (branching, renaming the trunk, merging from the command line) in a test environment or on a non-critical branch first.

I also haven't tried baseless merges. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668976.aspx) makes it sound similar to what you're doing, but also says that you have to use the TF command. I would think (hope) that there would still be a relationship between the branches after you renamed the trunk, though.